# gnudialer Make Problem

Tags: gcc, make, asterisk

I am trying to build [gnudialer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnudialer/?source=directory). I followed [these steps](http://www.howtoforge.com/automatic-dialer-with-asterisk-and-gnudialer) to the T.

Now on the last step, making the gnudialer, I get this error:

```
dispo.h:71:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
dispo.h: In function ‘char* dispo2short(int)’:
dispo.h:78:16: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
dispo.h: In function ‘char* dispo2long(int)’:
dispo.h:86:16: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
gnudialer.cpp: In function ‘void doRedirect(const string&, const string&, const string&, const string&, const string&, const string&, const bool&)’:
gnudialer.cpp:111:47: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]
gnudialer.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
gnudialer.cpp:310:10: error: ‘umask’ was not declared in this scope
gnudialer.cpp:1373:96: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]
make: *** [thegnudialer] Error 1
```

Any suggestions as to where the actual problem is? Done the so called "google" search on the world wide webs to no avail.

Comment: @maggotbrain here is the link http://www.howtoforge.com/automatic-dialer-with-asterisk-and-gnudialer

Comment: If anyone thinks this should not be reopened, I recommend commenting to explain why.

Comment: vicidial is probably more used -- you'd have to compare downloads, forum activity, etc.